# Cannot generate script file using SchemaExport

Tags: hibernate

I have a very simple script to generate my DLL for my database:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
   Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
   settings.put("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   settings.put("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
   settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase");
   settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
   settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
   settings.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
   settings.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
       .applySettings(settings)
       .build();
   MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
   metadata.addAnnotatedClass(AddressEntity.class);
   metadata.addAnnotatedClass(CompanyEntity.class);
    
   EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE);
   SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
   schemaExport.setOutputFile("myScript.sql");
   schemaExport.execute(enumSet, SchemaExport.Action.BOTH, metadata.buildMetadata());
}
```

If I look at the DEBUG and INFO information it is working. I can see the DLL statements being printed out.

The only problem I have is exporting it to a file. I have tried everything but **setOutputFile** does not seem to work for me. I cannot generate the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```java
EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE);
```

should be corrected to this:

```java
EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT);
```